# How can I create a require approval on workflow level rather than job level?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow including 3 jobs. Each job needs to access to a secret under `prod` environment:

```
name: test approval

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: prod
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          echo "job1: ${{ secrets.role }}"

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: prod
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          echo "job2: ${{ secrets.role }}"

  job3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: prod
    needs: job2
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          echo "job3: ${{ secrets.role }}"
```

I also have a require approval restriction rule on the `prod` environment to pause the deployment until someone approved the workflow. But the problem is that it requires approval for every job:

[image]

Is there a way to give workflow level approval, i.e. if the first job is approved, all subsequent jobs are approved automatically? I do need to use environment since the secrets are created inside environment.

I also come across [this plugin](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval) but it requires a keyword reply in a GitHub issue which is not easy to use.

Comment: yeah that plugin is pretty cumbersome, approvals at environment level make much more sense, just not the way it's implemneted. I dont get what the designers had in mind doing it, as the same people are required to review all those jobs, so unless one wants to manually inspect outputs of the previous job (meaning poor automation), what's the point of approving the same flow again. Seems to me like a bug tbh